# How do I fix a PHP script that isn't processing a form?

Tags: php

On a script of mine, it fails when I click the "Update" button. Basically, it will not check if the input fields are entered in correctly. In addition, if the form is filled out correctly, it will not actually update the information. In short, processing the error checks and update code aren't working. Here is my script.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid7906'];
$username = $_SESSION['username7906'];
$email = $_SESSION['email7906'];
$one = $_SESSION['yes7906'];
$zero = $_SESSION['no7906'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Profile Settings</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content=Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="./css/profile_settings.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$info = $_COOKIE['user7906']." <a href='./logout.php'>Log Out</a> <a    href='./memberpage.php'>Home</a> <b><a href='./profile.php?   user=$_COOKIE[user7906]'>Profile</a></b> > Edit <a href='./search.php'>User Search</a> <a   href='./account.php'>Account</a> <br/><hr/>";
$info2 = $_COOKIE['user7906']." <a href='./logout.php'>Log Out</a> <a    href='./memberpage.php'>Home</a> <b><a href='./profile.php?user=$username'>Profile</a></b> >    Edit <a href='./search.php'>User Search</a> <a href='./account.php'>Account</a> <br/><hr/>";
if (isset($_COOKIE['user7906']) && isset($_COOKIE['pass7906']) &&    isset($_COOKIE['email7906'])) {
                        echo $info."<br/>";

                        if (isset($_COOKIE['no7906'])) {
                            header("Location: ./profile.php?user=$_COOKIE[user]");
                        }
                        else { 
                            require('./connect.php');
                            $fgh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE   username='$_COOKIE[user7906]'");
                            $abc = mysql_num_rows("$fgh");
                            if ($abc !== 0) {

                                $osu = mysql_fetch_assoc($fgh);
                                $harv = $osu['id'];
                                $usr = $osu['username'];

                                    $et = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `profiles` WHERE users_id='$harv'");
                                    $elm = mysql_num_rows($et);
                                        if ($elm !== 0) {

                                            $c = mysql_fetch_assoc($et);
                                            $mm = $c['email'];
                                            $bio = $c['about'];
                                            $fnm = $c['first_name'];
                                            $lnm = $c['last_name'];
                                            $lc4 = $c['location'];


                                            echo "<center><b>Profile Settings</b></center><br/><br/>";

                                                    if (isset($_POST['submit']) === true) {
                                                    $value=$_REQUEST['fn'];
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                    $value=$fnm;
                                                    }


                                                if (isset($_POST['go']) === true) {
                                                    $value=$_REQUEST['fn'];
                                                    $value2=$_REQUEST['ln'];
                                                    $value3=$_REQUEST['email'];
                                                    $value4=$_REQUEST['about'];
                                                    $value5=$_REQUEST['locate'];

                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    $value=$fnm;
                                                    $value2=$lnm;
                                                    $value3=$mm;
                                                    $value4=$bio;
                                                    $value5=$lc4;
                                                }



                                            ?><center>
                                            <form action='./profile_settings.php' method='POST' name='lp' />
                                            <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>First Name:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='fn' value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Last Name:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='ln' value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Email:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='email' value="<?php echo $value3; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>About:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='about' value="<?php echo $value4; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Location:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='locate' value="<?php echo $value5; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </table>
                                                <center><input type='submit' name='go' value='Update' /> <?php echo "<a href='./profile.php?user=$_COOKIE[user7906]'>Cancel</a>"; ?></center>
                                            </center></form>


                                            <?php
                                            $go = $_POST['go'];
                                            $fn = $_POST['fn'];
                                            $ln = $_POST['ln'];
                                            $em = trim(strtolower($_POST['email']));
                                            $ab = $_POST['about'];
                                            $lc = $_POST['locate'];




                                            if (isset($go)==='Update') {


                                                if ((!empty($fn)) && (!empty($ln)) && (!empty($em)) && (!empty($ab)) && (!empty($lc)) && (strlen($em) > 6) && (strstr($em, "@")) == false && (strstr($em, ".")) == false) {


                                                    require("./connect.php");
                                                    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET first_name='$fn' WHERE users_id='$harv' ");
                                                    $update2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET last_name='$ln' WHERE users_id='$harv' ");
                                                    $update3 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET email='$em' WHERE users_id='$harv' ");
                                                    $update4 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET about='$ab' WHERE users_id='$harv' ");
                                                    $update5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET location='$lc' WHERE users_id='$harv' ");

                                                    echo '<br/>Profile updated successfully';







                                                }
                                                elseif (!isset($_POST)) {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Please fill out this form.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($fn)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your first name.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($ln)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your last name.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($em)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your email.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif ((strlen($em) < 7) || (strstr($em, "@")) === false || (strstr($em, ".")) === false) {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Invalid email</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($ab)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Write something about yourself.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($lc)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your location.</center>';
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                echo '<center>An error has occured.</center>';
                                                }



                                            }


                                        }
                                        else {
                                        header("Location: ./profile.php?user=$_COOKIE[user7906]");
                                        }

                            }
                            else {
                            echo '<center>An error has occured.</center>';
                            }



}







}
elseif(isset($username) && isset($userid) && isset($email)) {
                        echo $username.$info2."<br/>";



                            require('./connect.php');
                            $fgh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'");
                            $abc = mysql_num_rows($fgh);
                            if ($abc !== 0) {

                                $osu = mysql_fetch_assoc($fgh);
                                $harv = $osu['id'];
                                $usr = $osu['username'];

                                    $et = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `profiles` WHERE users_id='$harv'");
                                    $elm = mysql_num_rows($et);
                                        if ($elm !== 0) {

                                            $c = mysql_fetch_assoc($et);
                                            $mm = $c['email'];
                                            $bio = $c['about'];
                                            $fnm = $c['first_name'];
                                            $lnm = $c['last_name'];
                                            $lc4 = $c['location'];

                                            echo "<center><b>Profile Settings</b></center><br/><br/>";

                                                    if (isset($_POST['go']) === true) {
                                                        $value=$_REQUEST['fn'];
                                                        $value2=$_REQUEST['ln'];
                                                        $value3=$_REQUEST['email'];
                                                        $value4=$_REQUEST['about'];
                                                        $value5=$_REQUEST['locate'];
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        $value=$fnm;
                                                        $value2=$lnm;
                                                        $value3=$mm;
                                                        $value4=$bio;
                                                        $value5=$lc4;
                                                    }





                                            ?>

                                            <form action='./profile_settings.php' method='POST' name='lp' /><center>


                                            <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>First Name:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='fn' value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Last Name:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='ln' value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Email:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='email' value="<?php echo $value3; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>About:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='about' value="<?php echo $value4; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Location:</td>
                                                <td><input type='text' name='locate' value="<?php echo $value5; ?>" /><br/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </table>
                                                <center><input type='submit' name='go' value='Update' /> <?php echo "<a href='./profile.php?user=$username'>Cancel</a>"; ?></td></center>

                                            </center></form>


                                            <?php
                                            $go = $_POST['go'];
                                            $fn = $_POST['fn'];
                                            $ln = $_POST['ln'];
                                            $em = trim(strtolower($_POST['email']));
                                            $ab = $_POST['about'];
                                            $lc = $_POST['locate'];




                                            if (isset($go)==='Update') {


                                                if ((!empty($fn)) && (!empty($ln)) && (!empty($em)) && (!empty($ab)) && (!empty($lc)) && (strlen($em) > 6) && (strstr($em, "@")) == false && (strstr($em, ".")) == false) {


                                                    require("./connect.php");
                                                    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET first_name='$fn' WHERE users_id='$userid' ");
                                                    $update2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET last_name='$ln' WHERE users_id='$userid' ");
                                                    $update3 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET email='$em' WHERE users_id='$userid' ");
                                                    $update4 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET about='$ab' WHERE users_id='$userid' ");
                                                    $update5 = mysql_query("UPDATE `profiles` SET location='$lc' WHERE users_id='$userid' ");

                                                    echo '<br/>Profile updated successfully';







                                                }
                                                elseif (!isset($_POST)) {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Please fill out this form.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($fn)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your first name.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($ln)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your last name.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($em)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your email.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif ((strlen($em) < 7) || (strstr($em, "@")) === false || (strstr($em, ".")) === false) {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Invalid email</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($ab)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Write something about yourself.</center>';
                                                }
                                                elseif (isset($lc)==='') {
                                                echo '<br/><center>Enter your location.</center>';
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                echo '<center>An error has occured.</center>';
                                                }



                                            }


                                        }
                                        else {
                                        header("Location: ./profile.php?user=$username");
                                        }

                            }
                            else {
                            echo '<center>An error has occured.</center>';
                            }







}
else {
        echo "<center>Please <a href='./login.php'log in</a> for access to this page.</center>";
}

?>
```

Comment: If you're the author of this script you're probably the most confident person to fix it. Just take good old `var_dump` and do that!

Comment: We're not going to read hundreds of lines of code to try and debug this. Narrow it to the part that is actually problematic.

Comment: something tells me you should learn how to write your own functions

Comment: When I click "Update," the page reloads and the text fields display the proper input. However, if an error is expected, no error message appears. An example is if I leave the First Name field blank. It'll refresh, but the error message in the script won't display itself. Same concept for all of the error checks. Now, if the input fields are correct, I assume the error checks are irrelevant, and it'll go ahead and update the profile. Instead, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($go)==='Update') {
```

`isset()` returns either `true` or `false`, not a string.

Comment: I changed the isset() statements from the 'Update' string to true, and the error checks are running now. However, it will automatically say the "An error has occurred" message. I assume somewhere above that message, such as an elseif statement or the long check before it is supposed to update is incorrect. I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: I didn't realize I wrote $fgh as a string. I fixed it. That's my fault. Sorry. But, like I said before, the "An error has occurred" message keeps showing, so I assume an elseif() statement of mine is wrong and/or the:                                                   if ((!empty($fn)) && (!empty($ln)) && (!empty($em)) && (!empty($ab)) && (!empty($lc)) && (strlen($em) > 6) && (strstr($em, "@")) == false && (strstr($em, ".")) == false) {
 statement.